# IMU fall detection

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, imu

I am trying to detect a free fall scenario. I have accelerometer and gyroscope.
A simple fall I can detect by inspecting a total acceleration of 0g
However, my problem is when the IMU falls and rotates at the same time (centrifugal force). Any idea how to distinguish this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution, but let me state 2 points:

- if the IMU is near the center of mass of your hardware, the centrifugal acceleration should be negligible
- If you have a constant rotation you should read a constant rate on the gyroscope, and a constant acceleration too ( if the IMU is not in the center of mass). Morover, the constant rotation should be on an axis perpendicular to that of the constant rotation

Comment: the IMU  is not centred

Comment: So free fall with rotation can be detected with 2 conditions:

- constant gyro output, on some axis (which can be a combination of more than one gyro axes)
- constant acceleration on an axis which is perpendicular to the rotation axis